# AMQP Strategy to manage mobile offline data

Tags: android, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I m actually working on a little application with Android and NodeJS as backend.

I want to manage realtime data & offline data so I decided to use AMQP through RabbitMQ.

**My problem**

In my domain, a device is related to a place, and this place to a city. I want to be able to broadcast information to devices in a specific place, in a specific city.

I want to be able to have the message in a queue, and when all the devices in this queue have consumed the data, it's auto deleted by rabbitMQ, knowing that every devices dont consume the information at the same time (offline problems).

**Question**
What is the best strategy to manage this kind of problems ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html specifically about the `topic exchange`, which is what your probably want to use. In your case I think each device needs it's own queue bound to a topic exchange.